Which of the high-energy states or the low-energy states decides the superconducting transition temperature?
I wonder whether the electronic states whose energy sit at $\varepsilon \in[0,T_c]$ is essential in deciding $T_c$ in the weak-coupling theory of the superconductivity.
I was reading a note from prof. Coleman.
In Section 3.1.2 Exhaustion problem, it seems that he argues that it is the electrons in high energy $\varepsilon \in [T_K,D]$ where $\varepsilon$ is the enegy level of the electronic states measured from the Fermi level, $T_K$ and $D$ are the Kondo temperature and the cutoff (i.e. bandwidth), respectively, rather than the electrons states sitting in $\varepsilon \in [0,T_K]$.
The same analogy is applied to the case of Cooper pairs as summarized in Table 1 of the note.
This makes sense if I consider the linearized gap equation of the superconductivity in the weak-coupling regime, which is written as
\begin{equation}
g^{-1}=\int_{0}^{\omega {_\rm{D}}}{\rm{d}}\varepsilon N(\varepsilon) \frac{\tanh{\frac{\varepsilon}{2T_c}}}{\varepsilon}
\approx \log{\frac{\omega_{D}}{T_c}}.
\end{equation}
As it is seen, the major contribution to the logarithmic contribution comes from the states $\varepsilon>T_{c}$.
This contradicts to what I have learned: the electronic states close to the Fermi level determines the superconducting transition temperature. In other words, the existence of the Fermi surface is essential in the weak-coupling theory of the superconductor.
However, prof. Coleman arguement seems to mean that the superconductivity occurs when the Fermi surface is absent since states  $\varepsilon\in[0,T_c]$ have no role in deciding $T_c$. (I don't care whether the existence of the Fermi surface is a necessary condition in the strong coupling theory.)
Is my understanding of the implication of the weak-coupling gap equation correct or do I misunderstand prof. Coleman's argument?
